# How to watch document variable that initialized after create component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-tag-manager

I need to use variable `document.googleAnalytics` that added by google tag manager for A/B testing Vuejs page.
I tried initialize variable in `mounted` and `created` methods of component but I get `undefined`:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      myVar: null,
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    this.myVar = document.googleAnalytics; // undefined
  }
}
```

Also I tried use watch for `myVar` but it dose not help:

```
watch: {
  myVar(val) {
    this.myVar = val;
  }
}
```

It is possible to get value from document if tag manager script loaded after vue is already loaded and rendered?

Comment: Just to make sure, it is spelt *analitics* and not *analytics* right?

Comment: Nope, it is Analytics: https://analytics.google.com/

Comment: @Liang-ShihLin Analytics

Comment: When exactly is GTM script loaded? Try to postpone the assignment to document `load` event for starters.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could possibly use the Vue 'NextTick' function such as this:

```
mounted() {
  this.$nextTick(function () {
    // Code that will run only after the
    // entire view has been rendered
    this.myVar = val;
  })
}
```

Read more about the **Mounted** lifecycle step here:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted

Also, this is a pretty good guide for understanding 'NextTick':
https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2019/01/22/vue-what-is-next-tick/

Give it a go, let me know how you get on.

Comment: I think this is because vuejs scripts load faster than gtm